# How to use built-in HTML helpers within a custom HTML helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper, html.beginform

I'm trying to use BeginForm in a helper razor function eg.

```
@helper Modal(string name)
{
<div id="@name">

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "User", FormMethod.Post)) {
        <fieldset>
            @Html.Label("Name")
            @Html.TextBox("Name", new { @class = "text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" })
            @Html.Label("Email")
            @Html.TextBox("Email", new { @class = "text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" })

            <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
        </fieldset>
    }
</div>
}
```

However I am getting an error:

```
@MyHelper.Modal("dialog-form")
```

It's due to Html... markup, without it it obviously works fine with only html.

What am I missing to make it working?

I have added `@using System.Web.Mvc.Html;` but it still does not recognise FormMethod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately declarative helpers which are defined in `App_Code` folder seems to inherit from `System.Web.WebPages.HelperPage` instead of `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage` from which the normal cshtml files inherit.

It seems that the helper page also has a Html property but it's null.

However, it seems that you can access all this helpers through `PageContext.Page`. Also you'll need to add some using statements (all the namespaces from the web.config which is located in the views folder) so you can access important extensions methods like `Html.BeginForm`.

Here is a sample demo code:

```
@using System.Web.Mvc
@using System.Web.Mvc.Routing
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax
@using System.Web.Mvc.Razor
@using System.Web.Optimization

@helper MyCustomHelper()
{
    var wvp = PageContext.Page as System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage;

    var Html = wvp.Html;
    var Ajax = wvp.Ajax;
    var Url = wvp.Url;
    var ViewBag = wvp.ViewBag;

    // ... Helper code goes here ...

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "User", FormMethod.Post))

    @Ajax.BeginForm ...

    @Url.Action ...

    // ...
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Victor Form markup does not work eg. Html.BeginFrom, Ajax.BeginForm, Html.TextBox. I'm using Umbraco 7, however the markup works fine in umbraco view, it does not work only in the helper.